# HERE api reverse geocoder does not output street numbers

Tags: here-api

We are using HERE api REST version 7 to reverse geocode location through a freemium plan

```
GET https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/
    revgeocode
    ?at=48.2181679%2C16.3899064
    &apiKey=XXX
    &lang=en
```

We are observing that the returned addresses never contain street numbers, making the geocoded addresses useless in the context of our app.

Are we missing something ?

Comment: If it helps, I noticed that HERE.com says that their Reverse Geocoding API is currently "In Maintenance": on their API status page.

Comment: Reverse geocoding is actually not in maintenance and the above information is incorrect from @Dai.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of reverse geocoding (the API you shared) returns street names and not street numbers.

The old API that does not return street numbers:

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842%2C-87.6388%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=&&apiKey=APIKEY
```

New API that returns street names:

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=48.2181679%2C16.3899064&apiKey=APIKEY&lang=en
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request and the returned response contains `houseNumber` within `address` property:

**request**:

```
https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=48.2181679%2C16.3899064&apiKey=APIKEY&lang=en
```

**response**:

```
items": [
{
  "title": "Heinestraße 42, 1020 Vienna, Austria",
  "id": "here:af:streetsection:2VFm4oq5Zq8utAoSB90pmA:CgcIBCD6iaNNEAEaAjQy",
  "resultType": "houseNumber",
  "houseNumberType": "PA",
  "address": {
    "label": "Heinestraße 42, 1020 Vienna, Austria",
    "countryCode": "AUT",
    "countryName": "Austria",
    "state": "Vienna",
    "county": "Vienna",
    "city": "Vienna",
    "district": "2. Bezirk-Leopoldstadt",
    "street": "Heinestraße",
    "postalCode": "1020",
    "houseNumber": "42"
},
...
```

Comment: I have tried again and the street numbers are still not showing on our side.
I have noticed that received "id" & "resultType" are different than yours :
* id: here:af:streetsection:2VFm4oq5Zq8utAoSB90pmA
* resultType: street

Comment: Hmm. That is strange. It always returns the same response with houseNumber for me. I am afraid I can't help more.

Comment: For what is worth, we have tested in cities (eg Timisoara, Romania) where 5 years ago we were using HERE api. In this epoch, the HERE reverse geocoder was the best option (we selected it after testing possible alternatives, eg Google maps...).

Today, we observe that street numbers are most of the time missing (not always, we get numbers in say 10% of the case). It is sad to see a good product not being properly maintained.